# Sony Vaio: I can't type 'less and greater than' signs in TR keyboard layout

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, sony-vaio, characters

I have a strange trouble with my Sony Vaio VPCCW21FX. My laptop has a Turkish Q keyboard and I'm using TR keyboard layout on Windows 7 x64 Home Premium. The problem is, I cannot find a usual way to type `less than` or `greater than` signs unless I switch to EN keyboard layout. These signs are showed on the keyboard together with the Turkish letters "Ö" and "Ç", as you can see from the below photo of my laptop's keyboard.

So, how can I type these signs without switching to EN keyboard layout? I tried `Fn` and `Alt` keys but it doesn't work. I need to use TR layout since I need Turkish letters while writing my documents and e-mails.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are using the Turkish Q keyboard layout. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Turkey.svg) and [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/keyboards/kbdtuq.htm), you have to hold down the right `Alt` key (`AltGr`), then press the `"` key (topmost left) to type a `<` sign or the `1` key to type the `>` sign.

Comment: As the right Alt key is not labelled "AltGr", it might be that you have to press Ctrl+Alt to simulalte AltGr-behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, you eased my pain! It's interesting that there is `<` sign on `"` key whereas there is no sign for `>` on `1` key.